# Getting a error for Firebase Authentication in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I imported firebase into react and just tried making a simple login through google and keep getting errors I checked my package.json file for my dependencies and firebase was added and checked my firebase config file and its all right.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XTIC.png)
[This is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pdKE.png)

I tried chatgpt but that wasnt that helpful

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

you are using Web namespaced API but you should use latest Web modular API.

Below Code will help you to make simple login using Google Provider.

make sure you enabled Google Provider in Firebase project console.

in `firebase.js`

```
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

export const auth = getAuth(app)
```

*add your project keys.*

and in this `App.js`

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

const AuthExample = () => {
    const handleSignIn = async () => {
        const user =  await signInWithPopup(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider()).then((user) => {
            alert('Success');
        })
    }

    return <div>
        <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In with Google</button>
    </div>
}

export default AuthExample;
```

To learn more about authentication using Google with JavaSript read [this official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin).

Let me know if it works.